# macOS 11.4 Beta blocking website saying invalid certificate on clearly valid certificate

Tags: macos, web, ssl-certificate

I was trying to access gearpatrol.com recently from my RSS reader and getting a blank page, so I tried from Safari, Firefox, Brave and Chrome and get `ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID` for the site.  This happens from incognito modes as well... However, the certificate, when viewing it, states it's valid, and properly lists the website in its list of DNS names.  The website works fine from my phone and my wife's computer.  I tried to delete the GlobalSign certificates from Keychain, but I am blocked from doing so for some reason (Unix not allowed).

What could be going wrong with my laptop only?  How can I fix it?

edit: OSX 11.4 Beta (20F5046g)

Comment: What is your macOS version?

Comment: 11.4 Beta (20F5046g), updating main question to include info

Comment: Beta software is known to have bugs, it looks like you found one :-) For the record, I'm running the latest public Big Sur version (11.2.3) and don't have any trouble loading https://www.gearpatrol.com.